# How to set shape's size from another shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to set shape's size basing on the size of another shape produced by the `fit` environment. The MWE I use is the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\tikzset{
  node distance = 1.5cm,
  block/.style = {
    text width = 3cm,
    minimum height = 2cm,
    draw = blue!80,
    fill = blue!20
  },
  module/.style = {
    draw = black!50,
    fill = yellow!20,
    inner sep = 10pt
  }
}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node[block]                (B1) {B1};
  \node[block, right = of B1] (B2) {B2};

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[module, fit = (B1) (B2)] (F) { }; 
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I want is to add one more yellow shape below with the exact size of shape `F`:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two possible options:

1. Draw a rectangle using the corners of the `F` node, shifting it down a bit:

   ```
   \filldraw [draw=black!50,fill=yellow!20] ([yshift=-4cm]F.south west) rectangle ([yshift=-4cm]F.north east);
   ```
2. Use the `calc` library to calculate the width/height of `F` with the `let` operation, and create a node with these dimensions.

   ```
   \draw let
     \p1=(F.south west),\p2=(F.north east),\n1={(\x2-\x1)},\n2={(\y2-\y1)} in
     node[module,minimum width=\n1,minimum height=\n2,below=6cm of F.south] (F2) {};
   ```

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc}

\tikzset{
  node distance = 1.5cm,
  block/.style = {
    text width = 3cm,
    minimum height = 2cm,
    draw = blue!80,
    fill = blue!20
  },
  module/.style = {
    draw = black!50,
    fill = yellow!20,
    inner sep = 10pt
  }
}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node[block]                (B1) {B1};
  \node[block, right = of B1] (B2) {B2};

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[module, fit = (B1) (B2)] (F) { }; 
  \end{pgfonlayer}

  \filldraw [draw=black!50,fill=yellow!20] ([yshift=-3cm]F.south west) rectangle ([yshift=-3cm]F.north east);

  \draw let
  \p1=(F.south west),\p2=(F.north east),\n1={(\x2-\x1)},\n2={(\y2-\y1)} in
  node[module,minimum width=\n1,minimum height=\n2,below=3.3cm of F.south] (F2) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]